# Customize parsing for string array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, parsing

I have a an array of strings like this (from Twitter):

```
String str= "The Green New Deal is viable. It is the same vision that FDR had for his New Deal programs: nationwide mobilization http://94739 #thegreendeal #nationwide"
```

What I want is to 1) turn this string into an array and 2) remove stop words and include stemming 3) remove all characters except for '#' which indicates a term is a hashtag.

So I have tried to use this cool library https://github.com/uttesh/exude which does stemming and removes stop words, and lowercases and removes characters. The problem is this removes the hashtags. 
Code for this:

```
String tweetString = ExudeData.getInstance().filterStoppingsKeepDuplicates(str);
```

I have also tried this:

```
String[] wordArray = str.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]", "").toLowerCase().split("\\s+");
```

But this also removes hashtags. Any workaround using either method to keep the hashtags? (I'd prefer to keep the exude library for this)

Comment: Extract the hashtags before processing. Append back in after processing if needed.

Comment: great idea, can you show me what this looks like please?

Answer (score 1):

Using the regex method, you can try to add `#` in the list of characters that should not be removed like this :

```
        String[] wordArray = str.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z #]", "").toLowerCase().split("\\s+");
```